# Efficient way to iterate through numpy arrays in parallel and create a new resultant array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, python-3.x

I have 3 numpy arrays `dm_w, dm_s` and `dm_p`. I am in need of iterating through these arrays in parallel, do some computation based on a check condition as shown in code below.

My code works well for smaller arrays, but takes too long with larger arrays. I need an efficient and faster method to achieve this. Need some expert opinion.

**My code:**

```
prox_mat = []
for w_dist, s_dist, PI in zip(np.nditer(dm_w), np.nditer(dm_s), np.nditer(dm_p)):
    if PI == 0.0:
         proximity_score = ((w_dist + len(np.unique(dm_s) * s_dist)) / 
                           (dm_w.shape[0] * len(np.unique(dm_s))))
         prox_mat.append(proximity_score)
    else:
         proximity_score = ((w_dist + len(np.unique(dm_s) * s_dist)) / 
                           (dm_w.shape[0] * len(np.unique(dm_s)))) * log10(10 * PI)
         prox_mat.append(proximity_score)

ps = np.array(prox_mat)
ps = np.reshape(ps, dm_w.shape)
```

Comment: Looks to me like you could compute np.unique once rather than every time through the loop. That may save you lots of time without having to parallelize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things. One, computation of `np.unique(dm_s)` should be pulled outside of the loop. Even further, it looks like:

```
len(np.unique(dm_s) * s_dist) == len(np.unique(dm_s))
```

Which should either be pulled out of the loop or is a mistake. In any case..

We should just vectorize the forloop/append construct:

```
dm_s_uniques = len(np.unique(dm_s))
logs = np.log10(10 * dm_p)
logs[logs == -np.inf] = 1
prox_mat = ((dm_w +  dm_s_uniques) / (dm_w.shape[0] * dm_s_uniques)) * logs

ps = np.reshape(ps, dm_w.shape)
```

It looks like I map

Comment: Moving out np.unique did kind of helped it. Is there even a better method for quick parallel iteration? Since the matrices I am dealing with certain cases are huge.

Comment: Have you considered using cython? I have sometimes got a x10 faster code by using cython.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar how big is "huge" here?

Comment: @DanielThaagaardAndreasen Vectorizing it (as above) should be about the same as cython. If that's still not fast enough parallelizing should get it to about as fast as his machine can do it.

Comment: @U2EF1  Vectorizing it ? can you be a little more elaborate here. I am  not able to grasp your point and code above.

Comment: @ArunprasathShankar Numpy provides efficient routines for operations on vectors. If I have a np.array a, then 3*a is much faster than np.array([3*i for i in a]). Thus the code given here is about as fast as it can be in Cython, for less effort. Since we can also do the computation piecemeal, parallelizing would be the next step.